# Application version of JAR and RPM file fetching and storing as a parameter of config file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I want to store the application version of Jar and RPM in the API calls using the actuator/ info endpoints.
The application.config file is lying in the resources and I changed and activated the info endpoint need to fetch the value of Jar and RPM, and store it as properties in the config and use the actuator to call it to code, using the info endpoint.

Comment: Why using an RPM ? Where is the relationship?

Comment: These are the project requirements and i need both rpm version and jar version back in project after these are created